# getting internet connection to iPad and PC from one phone line

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipad

I have had the phone line that my PC was connected to routed to another room and now can't get internet service. It doesn't have wifi so want to know if it's possible to split the connection and hard wire the PC. The router is a Sky router to which my phone line is connected that gives me wifi and broadband connectivity to most of my flat but runs out of strength in the location of my PC.

Comment: Surely the router has LAN ports? It's really just a matter of installing a network cable.

Comment: I do get internet/broadband/wifi to tv and mobile devices but this service drops right off once I go into the room the original router was positioned next to my computer. That router and my non-wifi PC is still in its original location but the operating router is at another location and is connected to the now relocated phone cable. I have tried to boost network using Netgear range extenders and  Sky Wifi contact units but to no avail. Are you saying I can connect each router by an Ethernet cable directly and it will work.

Comment: I’m sorry, it seems I misinterpreted the question earlier. While theoretically possible, you usually cannot dial in (with two modems!) twice with the same user account. So you’ll have to get a connection to where your router is now. There’s just no other way.